# Hash Functions which are used and more popular

Tags: security, hash

I know the list of all hash functions is too long. I just want to know the most popular ones which are used in day to day IT practical tasks. I know MD5, SHA1, SHA2 (256 and 512) are really popular. Is there any other hash function I can add to these 5 algorithms?

I want to develop a hash Tool and I just want to include those algorithms that developers really need.

Comment: That's pretty much all of them, but you could add http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt and if you still need more, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_(cryptography) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlpool_(cryptography)

Comment: The list of function alone doesn't make sense. Hashes besides having different length have other specifics such as speed of calculation and intended purpose. So I am voting to close this question as not useful.

Comment: In which context? Hashing files? Hashing passwords? Those two areas use completely different functions.

Comment: Any context. I want to create a general tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most widely used (and defined in standards for SSL/TLS, OpenPGP, SSH) are:

- CRC32 - simple checksum, used in ZIP, OpenPGP and number of other
  standards.
- MD2, MD5 - too old and weak MD5 - old and considered weak.
- SHA1 - standard de facto, used almost everywhere (DSA algorithm is
  used only with SHA1, that's also wide usage area).
- SHA224/256/384/512 - should supersede SHA1, and is used with DSA keys
  larger than 1024 bits, and ECDSA signatures
- RipeMD160 - used in OpenPGP, and some X.509 certificates.

There are also other hash algorithms  (you can get the full list on wikipedia), but most likely you'll never meet them in real life.

Answer (score 7):

- MD5, SHA-1 - Commonly used, used to be secure, but no longer collision resistant
- SHA-2 - Commonly used, secure. It's a family of functions with different output size.
- SHA-3 - Not yet specified, but will probably become popular after that. Wait for the spec. Will be a family of functions.
- CRC32 - Not secure, but really common as checksum
- MD4, RIPEMD160 - Haven't seen those for hashing files, but they're still around in some other contexts. MD4 is broken, some older members of the RIPEMD family are broken, but RIPEMD160 is still secure. Only place I've seen whirlpool is TrueCrypt's KDF.
- TTH / TigerTreeHash - Used in some filesharing contexts, still secure but security margin grows thin
- ED2K - Used in some filesharing contexts, MD4 based, broken collision resistance
- Skein, Blake2 - Skein is a SHA-3 finalist, Blake2 is derived from one. Relatively fast in software and occasionally used but not really common. As a contributor to Blake2 I hope it gets more popular :)

Beyond the hashes you named CRC32 is really common, and TTH/ED2K are used in a filesharing context but rarely elsewhere. Haven't seen much of the other hashes in a file hashing context.

Answer (score 2):

`bcrypt` and `scrypt`. These are meant for password hashing.

`bcrypt` has been around for quite a long time, and it's considered safe. `scrypt` is a newer one, and it applies some memory intensive operations to prevent brute-force attacks with GPU.

Comment: In the context of password hashing one could also use PBKDF2 and the SHA-2 based crypt variants. In a legacy context there are also MD5Crypt and DES based crypt.

Comment: bcrypt is not hash function, it is password derivation algorithm, based on Blowfish cipher

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky - If you want to be exact we should call it a "key-derivation-function", though BCrypt is commonly referred to as hash function for passwords. Often you have to explain that passwords should be hashed instead of encrypted, so it would only confuse people more if you say it is not a hash function.

Answer (score 0):

- In case you just want to add hash functions in your tool, irrespective of security, then MD-4 and NIST SHA-1 and SHA-2 competition finalists can be implemented.
- For newer and more secure hash functions, SHA-3 winner (Keccak) can be implemented.

[NIST hash function competition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIST_hash_function_competition)

[SHA-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keccak)

Comment: Do you know any software implementation of SHA-3?

Comment: @ehsun7b There is no final specification for SHA-3 yet. NIST will probably apply some minor tweaks to Keccak before calling it SHA3. So I'd wait until it's officially specified before implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decide if you want fast, insecure hash functions, or slow, secure ones.

Of these the best are currently:

- Fast: CRC32 on SSE4.2/armv7 HW, Murmur3, CityHash, FNV
- Secure: SHA-3 (Keccak), SHA-2, BLAKE2

See https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/w/list for a testing framework of some popular ones.

*[Edit note: prev. had bcrypt, scrypt as secure+slow hash functions, but they are just password hash functions]*

Comment: Bcrypt and scrypt are password hashes, they're not secure as crytographic hashes and they're deliberately slow. SHA-2 and BLAKE2 on the other hand are secure cryptographic hashes, with the latter being slightly faster. It doesn't really make sense to list them in the same list.

Comment: You are right. Improved it. The question was too broad.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to study about DES and TDES, they do encryption with key and will be good choice for you if u need to encrypt/decrypt data with public / private key.

Comment: Neither DES nor 3DES support encryption of data with public/private key. They are symmetric algorithms.

Comment: Also, DES and TDES are not hash functions.

Comment: Triple DES uses a "key bundle" which comprises three DES keys, K1, K2 and K3, each of 56 bits (excluding parity bits)

Comment: My question is about hash functions not public key encryption algorithms.